# How to retrieve particular values from df.collect() result in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame `df` in PySpark.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

df = spark\
        .read \
        .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
        .load("my_index/my_mapping") \
        .groupBy(["id", "type"]) \
        .agg(
            func.count(func.lit(1)).alias("number_occurrences"),
            func.countDistinct("host_id").alias("number_hosts")
        )

ds = df.collect()
```

I use `collect` because the amount of data after grouping and aggregating is always small and fits into memory.
Also, I need to use `collect` because I pass `ds` as a parameter of `udf` function.
The function `collect` returns an array. How can I make the following queries to this array: **for the given `id` and `type`, return `number_occurrences` and `number_hosts`**.

For example, let's imagine that `df` contains the following rows:

```
id   type   number_occurrences   number_hosts
1    xxx    11                   3
2    yyy    10                   4
```

After doing `df.collect()`, how can I retrieve `number_occurences` and `number_hosts` for `id` equal to `1` and `type` equal to `xxx`.
The expected result is:

```
number_occurrences = 11
number_hosts = 3
```

**Update:**

Maybe there is the more elegant solution?

```
    id = 1
    type = "xxx"
    number_occurrences = 0
    number_hosts = 0
    for row in ds:
        if (row["id"] == id) & (row["type"] == type):
            number_occurrences = row["number_occurrences"]
            number_hosts = row["number_hosts"]
```

Comment: `collect()` doesn't return a Dataset, it returns an array on your driver.

Comment: @mtoto: You are right. Updated.

Comment: Still I don’t understand why you need to use collect. You can achieve same result from the resultant dataframe

Comment: do you always have to give the `type`? If your `id` is unique, you could order the list by id and then directly access the element at a specific position

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` is unique, which should be the case for an id, you can sort the array based on the id. This just ensures the correct order and if your id is sequential you can directly access the record and substract the id by 1

```
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([
(1,"xxx",11,3),(2,"yyyy",10,4),

], ("id","type","number_occurrences","number_hosts"))
id = 1
type = "xxx"
sorted_list = sorted(test_df.collect(), cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x["id"],y["id"]))
sorted_list[id-1]["number_occurrences"],sorted_list[id-1]["number_hosts"]
```

The Result:

```
(11, 3)
```